# How to make a question pop up upon a answer to previous question google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to see my form and as im taking my form if one of the questions says yes then another question related to that question pops up.

Example: Do you know where u want to take pictures? Answer: yes (another question pops up and says) where do you want to take the pictures

I am still new to learning google script and I am originally a JS developer

Comment: Being a JS developer you should have no problem building a webapp to do that for you. But as far a google forms is concerned I don't think so.

Comment: well im not a good js dev im still learning but i cant find anything that helps me to solve what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already enabled natively to Google Forms and no Scripting/Coding is needed. See this article [Show questions based on answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) on some steps on achieving this.